# Get data with $resource from Flask API in AngularjJS

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm using a Flask rest api where I've a method that I call from AngularJS with $resource factory.

I'm using now data to try it, this is the simplified code in the server:

`return jsonify({'teacher': 'Tom'})`

And in AngularJS, in a controller where I want to get data:

```
var teacher = $resource('http://localhost:8001/entities/teacher/:id');

teacher.get({id: 1}).$promise.then(function(teacher) {
               // success
               $scope.teacher = teacher;

            }, function(errResponse) {
               // fail
               console.log('fail')
               console.log(errResponse)
            });
```

And this is the log in web browser console:

```
fail 
Object { data: null, status: -1, headers: fd/<(), config: Object, statusText: "" }
```

But however I can see the request in network console with data in response with 200 status code, because of this I think that I don't know how read this data from $resource response, I've search info about this but I don't know how if I can see the data the resource give mi a fail error.

Any idea?

I know that I should to have this code in a service in another file, it's only a sample to find the solution.

Thanks!

Update:
I think that the problem is in the headers that I received from the server. If I try to use $http with a url that I found as example this work perfect, but when I try the same with my own server this fail even though I can see the response (and it's fine in the network console and it's fine with curl test) I think that the problem is in the headers, maybe $http or $resource needs a specific headers. I' ve updated the original question, I hope that someone can help me. I'm sure that the response is application/json.

This is the test url:
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
and the header that is returned is:

Cache-Control
public, max-age=14400
Content-Encoding
gzip
Content-Type
application/json; charset=utf-8
Date
Mon, 03 Oct 2016 07:43:11 GMT
Etag
W/"160d-MxiAGkI3ZBrjm0xiEDfwqw"
Expires 
Mon, 03 Oct 2016 11:43:11 GMT
Pragma
no-cache
Server
cloudflare-nginx
Vary
Accept-Encoding
Via 
1.1 vegur
X-Firefox-Spdy
h2
X-Powered-By
Express
access-control-allow-credentials
true
cf-cache-status 
HIT
cf-ray
2ebec303f9f72f7d-MAD
x-content-type-options
nosniff

And my header is:

Cache-Control
no-cache
Content-Length
35
Content-Type
application/json
Date
Mon, 03 Oct 2016 08:26:00 GMT
Expires 
Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Link
Server
Development/2.0

I'm using a Google App Engine developer Server (I don't know if this is relevant).

Comment: have you tried using `$http` instead of `$resource`? It does the same thing, it's a little easy to understand, here is the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: can you show us the network? (request line)

Comment: @medev21 I thought that $resource it's better than $http, in other project I used $resource but with another code more complex that I don't understand really fine, but I liked the idea behind, because of this I would like understand fine this.

Comment: @CemArguvanlı , it's : `GET http://localhost:8001/entities/teacher/1`

Comment: i think from this line `teacher.get({id: 1}).$promise.then(function(teacher)`, teacher inside  the function is the response, I would name it response, so your scope should be something like this `$scope.teacher = response.data.teacher`.  Also, there is no need to add localhost in the url (it might be the problem), just do `/entities/teacher/1`

Comment: @medev21 I've tried that you say but It doesn't work for me. About your second advice, I don't think that it's the problem because I can see the answer of request  fine in the network console.But thanks anyway.